# Web Server and App Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I just want to know that how the web server call to app server code and pass the response to the client, Eg :-

```
Nginx web serve
Unicorn app server
Rails application
```

Our request sends to web server and how web server(nginx) pass that request to the app server(unicorn) and how app server runs the rails code or route and sends back the response.

Comment: Check out this blog post at github. It does a great job of explaining how unicorn works alongside nginx: https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn

Comment: Well, the requests are handled by the two services, Nginx and Unicorn. Nginx receives the request, which consists of a method, headers and data. It then proxy-passes it to the application server as a new request, according to its (Nginx) configuration. Unicorn receives the request and (via JS Runtime I think) the routing is handled and the request head to the adequate controller where ruby code is executed. The result is passed back to the Nginx via the Unicorn (because it needs to be served). Nginx serves the proxy data received to the client.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the collaboration of a web server to an app server you must study the architecture of the server first. I guess [this link](http://www.aosabook.org/en/nginx.html) will give you a good idea about architecture and it's bonding.

Have a look here:
[image]

Comment: Hmm. this blog was really helpful but i need some more deep details